# How to apply the parvo/amplo akamptisomeric stereodescriptors to this bicyclic system?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers, conformers

I'm looking for examples of [*akamptisomerism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamptisomer)<sup>[1]</sup>.
I'm try to find simple molecules able to (theoretically) show this kind of isomerism.
I thought about the isomers of [(2*R*)-2-methyl-9-oxabicyclo[3.3.1]nonane](https://embed.molview.org/v1/?mode=balls&smiles=[C@]([H])12CC[C@]([H])(C)[C@]([H])(O1)CCC2).
Considering only the $\ce{(HC)O(CH)}$ group, I found the eight akamptisomers.

[image: RpRa][image: RaRp]
$\hspace{5em} \ce{(1$R$_p,2$S$,5$R$_a)} \hspace{7em} \ce{(1$R$_a,2$S$,5$R$_p)}$

[image: RpSp][image: RaSa]
$\hspace{5em} \ce{(1$R$_p,2$S$,5$S$_p)} \hspace{7em} \ce{(1$R$_a,2$S$,5$S$_a)}$

[image: SpRp][image: SaRa]
$\hspace{5em} \ce{(1$S$_p,2$S$,5$R$_p)} \hspace{7em} \ce{(1$S$_a,2$S$,5$R$_a)}$

[image: SpSa][image: SaSp]
$\hspace{5em} \ce{(1$S$_p,2$S$,5$S$_a)} \hspace{7em} \ce{(1$S$_a,2$S$,5$S$_p)}$

Could the **(3*S*)-3-methyl-11,12-dioxabicyclo[4.4.2]dodecane** show akamptisomerism too?
What descriptor to use? Is this also akamptisomerism or will be another (new?) kind of isomerism?

[image: Isomer 1][image: Isomer 2]
$\hspace{5em} \ce{(1$R$_?,3$S$,6$R$_?)} \hspace{7em} \ce{(1$R$_?,3$S$,6$R$_?)}$

[image: Example 01 rotating]
$$\ce{(1$R$_?,3$S$,6$R$_?)}$$

**Reference**

1. [Canfield, P. J.; Blake, I. M.; Cai, Z.-L.; Luck, I. J.; Krausz, E.; Kobayashi, R.; Reimers, J. R.; Crossley, M. J., A new fundamental type of conformational isomerism. *Nature Chemistry* **2018**, *10*, 615–624.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/s41557-018-0043-6)